# How to pass a file select event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a file input element

```
<input type="file" id="url" name="url[]" multiple />
```

Now the code that listen's to its on change event

```
document.getElementById('url').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

The function

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
}
```

This works perfectly fine ..!!

But this does not

```
<input type="file" id="url" name="url[]" multiple onchange="handleFileSelect()" />
```

It throws an error "TypeError: evt is undefined"

how to get the event passed for the second one as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `event` as a parameter to the `handleFileSelect` method.

Try

```
<input type="file" id="url" name="url[]" multiple onchange="handleFileSelect(event)" />
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zw33D/)

Comment: Yeah, this works fine but how does the first one was able auto pass the event?

Comment: @ClainDsilva in the one you are passing the handler as a function reference and it is invoked by the js engine... but in the second one you are invoking the function in the inline handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#url").change(function(){
        var th = $(this);
        //some action
    });
});
```